# Which query reproduces city street network orientation plots using OSMnx?

Tags: python, osmnx

We are interested in reproducing the street network orientation plots from [this blog post](https://geoffboeing.com/2019/09/urban-street-network-orientation/) using OSMnx. However, using the modified [example notebook code](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/17-street-network-orientations.ipynb)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox

ox.config(log_console=True)
weight_by_length = False

ox.__version__

# define the study sites as label : query
places = {
    "Berlin": "Berlin, Germany",
    "Munich": "München, Germany",
    "Minneapolis": "Minneapolis, MN, USA",
}

# verify OSMnx geocodes each query to what you expect (i.e., a [multi]polygon geometry)
gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf(list(places.values()))
gdf

# create figure and axes
n = len(places)
ncols = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)))
nrows = int(np.ceil(n / ncols))
figsize = (ncols * 5, nrows * 5)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=figsize, subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})

# plot each city's polar histogram
for ax, place in zip(axes.flat, sorted(places.keys())):
    print(ox.utils.ts(), place)

    # get undirected graphs with edge bearing attributes
    G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type="drive")
    Gu = ox.add_edge_bearings(ox.get_undirected(G))
    fig, ax = ox.bearing.plot_orientation(Gu, ax=ax, title=place, area=True)
```

our results differ from those in the blog post:
[our Berlin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtEr2.png) [Geoff's Berlin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv6Mj.png) [our Minneapolis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38sNa.png) [Geoff's Minneapolis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAzEB.png) (sorry, I'm not allowed to embed images)

As Geoff mentions in his blog post, that "cities proper (municipalities), not wider metro areas or urban agglomerations" are used, we speculated that choosing the appropriate admin-level in the query might help. However using, e.g.,

```
gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_place('Minneapolis, MN, USA', {'boundary':'administrative','admin_level':'8'})
```

returns a multitude of polygons, where it is unclear to us how to select from them. The unary union

```
gdf_unified = gdf[gdf.admin_level=='8'].unary_union
```

does not seem to do the trick:
[Minneapolis, unary union, admin-level 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNDU0.png)

Can anyone advise which query to use to successfully reproduce the plots?

Comment: Start with setting `area=False` as that will be closer to the methodology in the [article](https://appliednetsci.springeropen.com/articles/10.1007/s41109-019-0189-1) from which that image derives. If I recall correctly (it's been a while), [this](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=136712&class=boundary)  was probably the Minneapolis definition used, for example.

Comment: That all seems to check out now, thanks so much for the quick reply, Geoff!